# Returning JSON with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

There is any way with this bundle to get JSON (not forms) as response?
Clients are mobile devices and I think it's simpler work with JSON so I don't need to integrate webviews.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) ... It provides listeners to easily return JSON, XML ... and integrates [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle) nicely.

Then you can use [bundle inheritance](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html) to return JSON data by default where you need it.